# PHP LDAP binding successfully with incorrect password sometimes

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently integrating LDAP Authentication. I'm able to connect to my LDAP AD server, and query it for data anonymously, which is fine. I'm trying to authenticate users now, and when I enter my username and a random password, it successfully fails, and when I enter my real password, it successfully passes, however I'm able to enter MOST of my correct password, and it still passes.

e.g.:

```
Username: user1
Password: RandomPassword1
(works)

Username: user1
Password: Random
(fails)

Username: user1
Password: RandomPasswo
(works???)
```

So now I'm curious if Active Directory maybe doesn't check the whole password, maybe it can't, or maybe the hashing algorithm it uses generates the same hash code for RandomPassword1 as RandomPasswo?

I guess my question is that^, but also is there a way to ensure it authenticates properly? 
I haven't tested this with other passwords, as I don't have access to other accounts to test this with, however it definitely works when the password is RandomPassword1 (which happens to have been my password, yes - I've changed it now)

Edit: My LDAP Binding code:

```
function validateLoginDetails($username, $password) {
    $ldap_connection = ldap_connect("server", 389);
    if($ldap_connection === FALSE) {
        echo "Unable to connect.";
    } else {
        ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die("Could not set version.");
        ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    }
    $r = @ldap_bind(@$ldap_connection, "uid=".$username.",ou=People,o=Foo", $password);
    if(!$r) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

(Note that using the same connection, I'm able to list all users and their info, and it does reject a randomly mashed password, but it accepts as I said, a half-complete password. Maybe this is an option in AD or LDAP?)

(I've also realised that even though I've changed my password, my new password doesn't work, but the old password, RandomPassword1, still does, but I'm assuming this is because maybe AD takes a while to update or something? I'm not sure.)

Comment: Can you give us a code sample on how you do the authentication? This should not happen, therefore I'm curious how you implemented the login to see what happens there....

Comment: I've added the function now. Maybe it's something to do with me supressing the warnings?

Comment: normaly the new password should work immediately. There seems to be something else in your AD not working properly

Comment: Sorry, should have specified better - I changed my password, and logging into Windows it's fine, just the LDAP binding still works with the old password/half password. Is my authentication function above okay?

Comment: the code seems to be ok even though I'd have done it differently. I'd remove the error suppression on the ldap_bind to see wjhether there are any messages from the server. But due to the missing synchronisation between AD and the server you are binding to there seems to be something different going on.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I just had the same "problem", ran accross your question, and found out what was causing (in my case, at least). So I thought I would describe how I solved it for those interested (even though it probably won't be of your particular interest anymore).

In my case, I found it to be because the user I was trying to authenticate with a "similar" password (the correct password minus or plus a few characters) had the password encrypted with the Unix Crypt method (it was in a machine used solely for development purposes, so not a big deal).

It probably only considered a fixed short length of the password to generate the hash, thus the las few characters of the password attempted not mattering.

I then set the user's password using a stronger encryption method (like SHA-512 Crypt) and it only recognized the exact correct password, as expected.